# Why can't read array child elements from json response in reactjs?

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

I get data json:

```
componentDidMount() {
        const {axios} = this.props
        const {invoice} = this.state

                axios({
                    method: 'get',
                    url: `/invoice`,
                }).then((result) => {
                    this.setState({invoice: result.data})
                }).catch((error) => {
                    this.setState({error: error.response.data[0]})
                })

    }
```

and my json data is like this:

```
{"branchId":"c3","id":"30","invoiceLines":[{"id":"089","productId":"7c"}],"sumTotalPrice":2700}
```

I try to show the "invoiceLines"'s id like this:

```
return(
<Grid container>
    <Grid item xs={12}>

{this.state.invoice.invoiceLines.map((item, i) => {
    <p key={i}>{item.id}</p>
})}

    </Grid>
</Grid>
)
```

but catch this error:
TypeError: this.state.invoice.invoiceLines is undefined

Answer (score 3):

Loading data is async, `render` will be called without data at start. When data arrives `setState` will force view update - second `render`.

You need to prevent accessing not ready data - f.e. displaying 'loading'.

[Example from docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-ajax.html)

**UPDATE:**
Defining initial state (constructor) only covers a real problem and is only helpful in simple cases - one/two levels deep. In the case of deeper structures, this is not practical.

Answer (score 1):

I believe you have not defined your initialState in the constructor, or it is like `this.state = {invoice: []}`

Try defining initial state as `this.state = {invoice: {invoiceLines : []}}` in the constructor

If this suggestion doesnot work post more information about the component

Comment: please read @xadm answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/53139345/4960559 to understand why it has happened

Answer (score 1):

As someone previously mentioned, loading data is async. Changing `componentDidMount()` to `componentWillMount()` might solve your issue?